# Sorting a vector inside a custom class C++ using std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

How do I sort two vectors inside a custom class using std::sort?

As an example, let's say I have a class containing two vectors, ids and marks. After initializing the vectors, I would like to sort the elements of this class by marks, preserving the sorted order in the ids.

I've attempted to do this using the custom `std::sort` function.

```
class Example
{
public:
    void init();
    static bool sortByMarks(const Example &lhs, const Example &rhs);
    //....other functions

private:
    vector<int> ids;
    vector<int> marks;
    //....other variables   
}
void Partition::init()
{
    ids.resize(5);
    marks.resize(5);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
         ids[i]=i+1;
    marks[0]=47;marks[1]=44;marks[2]=88;marks[3]=52;marks[4]=46;
}
bool Partition::sortByMarks(const Example &lhs, const Example &rhs);
{
    return lhs.marks < rhs.marks;
}
```

EDIT: [This is fixed by adding the Example:: to the function call] I'm having trouble calling this function. I tried the following:

```
Example e; 
sort(&e, &e, Example::sortByMarks);
```

Sample Input:

`ids  : 1,2,3,4,5
marks: 47,44,88,52,46`

Sample Output:

`ids  : 2,5,1,4,3 
marks: 44,46,47,52,88`

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Marks vector is what I want sorted (ids should also be changed accordingly)

Comment: First, you need to add an ; at the end of your class. I have two question : you want to sort using the vector marks ?

Comment: What are you trying to sort, exactly? `e.marks`? And then having `e.ids` changed accordingly so as to maintain the id-marks pairing?

Comment: Do you want to sort both `ids` and `marks` with the `ids` array being sorted according to the `marks` value at the same index?  For example if you had and `ids = { 1, 2, 3}` and `marks = { 98, 54, 89 }` that you'd want the sorted arrays to look like: `id = {2, 3, 1}` and `marks = {54, 89, 98}`?

Comment: @MichaelBurr that's exactly what I want. I've added sample input/output to my question.

Comment: With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), [`ranges::sort(ranges::view::zip(marks, ids));`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98e934084be29fe0). This technically sorts by marks first, and then by ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with vectors like that. You need to couple ids with marks somehow, e.g using map, vector of pairs or like this:

```
class Example{
public:
    void init();
    void sortByMarks();

private:
    struct Students{
        int ids;
        int marks;
    };
    std::vector < Students > students;

};

void Example::sortByMarks(){
    std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(), [](Students a, Students b){
        return a.marks < b.marks;
    });
}


int main(){
    Example e;
    e.sortByMarks();
}
```

Or you could write your own sort:

```
void selection_sort(){
    int size = marks.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i = i + 1){
        int min = i;
        for (auto j = i + 1; j < size; j = j + 1){
            if (marks[j] < marks[min]){ min = j; }
        }
        std::swap(marks[i], marks[min]);
        std::swap(ids[i], ids[min]);    // add this extra line
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid this could be the solution, because I would have to change a lot in my actual code! Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could also write your own sort function. It would require only one additional line if you already have working sort algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

```
// .h file
class MarkersDetector
{
    public:
        void sortMarkers(std::vector<cv::Point2f> &markers);
        // Other functions...
    private:
        // Other variables...
};

// .cpp file
// Function for sort the marker points
bool comparePoints(cv::Point2f point1, cv::Point2f point2)
{
    if (point1.x < point2.x)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if ((point1.x == point2.x) && (point1.y < point2.y))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void MarkersDetector::sortMarkers(std::vector<cv::Point2f> &markers)
{
    std::sort(markers.begin(), markers.end(), comparePoints);
}
```

Comment: This is a brief example for use the std::sort function inside a class using a compare function, in this case the comparePoints function.

Comment: You can add information to your answer by using the "edit" button instead of posting a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are needed:

1. Since `sortByMarks` is a member of `Example` you need to tell the compiler the correct scope or the function will not be found:

   ```
   sort(e, e, Example::sortByMarks);
   ```
2. Then there is a problem because `sortByMarks` is a normal member function, and normal member functions expects a hidden first argument, which is a pointer to the instance the member function is being called on, and that becomes the `this` pointer inside the function. You can solve this by making the member function `static`:

   ```
   static bool sortByMarks(const Example &lhs, const Example &rhs);
   ```

There is also a third problem, and that is that the `std::sort` function won't actually, you know, *sort* anything. The way you're calling it, you are telling it to sort an array of size *zero*.

---

To be honest I don't think you thought things through completely with your problem. I'm guessing what you *really* want are several objects, each containing a *single* mark, and then sort the vector of objects containing the mark.

Something like

```
class Example
{
private:
    int mark;

public:
    Example(int m) : mark(m) {}

    int get_mark() const { return mark; }
};

bool operator<(const Example& e1, const Example& e2)
{
    return e1.get_mark() < e2.get_mark();
}

std::vector<Example> example_vector = {
    Example(5),
    Example(1),
    Example(3)
};

std::sort(std::begin(example_vector), std::end(example_vector));
```

Comment: I've edited the question with the init function. By adding the scope resolution, I was able to call the function. Thanks. But, it doesn't seem to be performing the sort :( am I still doing something wrong?